# How did early Christians practice and observe their new religion

Tags: early-church, worship

What did early Christians do after they were Baptized?

Some were originally Jews who maintained some aspects of their former observance. And others were Gentiles (viz. non-Jews in this context).

Conceivably there were numerous diverse sects.

But there must have been some specificity of worship that characterized them as Christian.

Comment: They focused on evangelizing and converting others  to “The Way”

Comment: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1101993004.   You may find this of interest

Comment: The answers to this question are all in Acts, the apostolic epistles and in the book of Revelation, particularly the first section to the seven churches. We just need to absorb all that is therein, to answer this question. Plus more reading of the early Church Fathers. I don't see that a 'summary' of this extensive and broad subject will help anyone.

Comment: One of the most pressing doctrine concerns in early 1st century Christianity was whether a person first had to become a Jew before he could become a Christian. It took a fair while before doctrine that we accept today as orthodox was accepted as such. There where a fair number of issues the early church faced that we simply have no accounts of Jesus discussing.

Comment: This seems too broad to me - there are so many things that could be discussed under the broad category of "worship".

Comment: practice and observe are definitely two different categories that both do fill volumes.

Answer (score 1):

You might like the [Didache](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Didache), written in Egypt or Syria in the 2nd century. It goes over several of the Ten Commandments, lists various sins, talks about baptizing in the name of the Trinity, instructs people to fast on Wednesdays and Fridays, says to pray the Lord's prayer and take the Eucharist seriously, etc. It's not a long read at all! [Full text here.](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0714.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Well just as there was the Sabbath, early Christians would gather together. They would have fellowship and the Holy Spirit was with them. Peter had stood up and preached sermons. And in Acts 2:42, "And they continued steadfastly in the apostles’ doctrine and fellowship, in the breaking of bread, and in prayers." They showed love and compassion for others and especially those in need. As they grew also Paul began to minister to churches in different areas and guide them as well to be led in the spirit.